# Как получить id новой записи после добавления в таблицу?

Tags: java, android, android-room

Есть таблица в базе данных Room, primary key у неё автоматически генерируется (выставлен флаг `autoGenerate`).

Подскажите, как я могу получить `id` новой записи после добавления?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это можно сделать, если в методе класса Dao указать тип `Long` в качестве возвращаемого значения. Об этом сказано [в документации](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/accessing-data#convenience-insert).

Предположим, у вас есть сущность `User`:

```java
@Entity
public class User {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    public int id;
    public String name;
}
```

И insert-метод Dao возвращает тип `Long`:

```java
@Dao
interface MyDao {

    @Insert
    Long insertUser(User user);

}
```

Тогда при вызове этого метода будет возвращаться `rowId`, который [будет соответствовать](https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html) новому `id` пользователя:

```java
Long id = dao.insertUser(user);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!